Minimize submatrix rank under constraints
I have a n by 2n binary matrix. I want to find a combination of m unique columns (for a fixed m), so that the new n by m matrix’s rank is minimized. My only constraint is that if I include column k, I also include column k + n.
I wrote a brute force code that works by checking every combination and computing the rank. It works fine. However, since I need n ~ 20-120 and k ~ 1-10, the computational time blows up. With chat GPT’s help I tried using CVXPY and Gurobipy. Gurobipy was super fast but it's not giving the right answer unless n >> k. This is surely something I'm doing wrong.
Here's the brute force code, binaryMatrix is the input matrix:
Ias = []
    
comb_array = np.array(list(combinations(range(len(tableau)), k)))
for columns_to_keep in comb_array:
    cutMatrix = binaryMatrix[:, np.concatenate([columns_to_keep, N + columns_to_keep])].astype(int)
    Ias.append(np.linalg.matrix_rank(cutMatrix))

rank = min(Ias)

